# MVC 4 Carrying View Model into two different HTML Forms view model not setted

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I m using two html forms in a one page and i have to carry my screen values into second submit for showing filter values. But when i submit second form i take empty view model on my controller.

here is my view model

```
public class MerchantRelationsViewModel
{
    public RelationsSelectCriteria Criteria { get; set; }
    public MerchantRelationsInfoSelectCriteria CriteriaInfo { get; set; }
    public MerchantRelations MerchantRelations { get; set; }

    public IList<MerchantRelationsSequenceRelationsDetailViewModel> SequenceRelationsList { get; set; }

    public IList<MerchantRelationsMerchantRelationsDetailViewModel> MerchantRelationsList { get; set; }

    public SelectList MerchantRelationComboList { get; set; }

    public int selectedItem { get; set; }
    public MerchantRelationsViewModel()
    {
        Criteria = new RelationsSelectCriteria();
        CriteriaInfo = new MerchantRelationsInfoSelectCriteria();
        MerchantRelations = new MerchantRelations();
        MerchantRelationsList = new List<MerchantRelationsMerchantRelationsDetailViewModel>();
        SequenceRelationsList = new List<MerchantRelationsSequenceRelationsDetailViewModel>();

    }



    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Merchant no cannot be null.")]
    [Display(Name = "Merchant No")]
    public long? MerchantNumber
    {
        get
        {
            if (Criteria.MerchantNumber == 0)
                return null;

            //2. criteria 
            CriteriaInfo.MerchantNumber = Criteria.MerchantNumber; 

            return Criteria.MerchantNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            Criteria.MerchantNumber = 0;
            if (value.HasValue)
                Criteria.MerchantNumber = value.Value;
        }
    }

    [Display(Name = "Merchant Name")]
    public string SignName
    {
        get
        {
            return MerchantRelations.SignName;
        }
        set
        {
            MerchantRelations.SignName = value;
        }
    }

    [Display(Name = "Merchant Type")]
    public string MainStoreFlagDscr
    {
        get
        {
            return MerchantRelations.MainStoreFlagDscr;
        }
        set
        {
            MerchantRelations.MainStoreFlagDscr = value;
        }
    }

    [Display(Name = "Query Type")]
    public int SelectedMerchantType
    {
        get
        {
            return CriteriaInfo.Option;
        }
        set
        {
            CriteriaInfo.Option = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Here s my index I'm using display templates for showing both labels and fields

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("QueryMerchantRelations", "MerchantRelations", FormMethod.Post, new {}))
{

    <div class="criteria-form criteria-form-three-col">
        <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="three-column-left">
               @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MerchantNumber, Web.Constants.CompenentNameConstants.DisplayTemplates.NumberOnlyTextBox)
            </div>
            <div class="three-column-middle">
                <input type="submit" class="nar-btn nar-form-size75" value="Bul" />
            </div>
            <div class="three-column-right">
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SignName, Web.Constants.CompenentNameConstants.DisplayTemplates.DisplayTextForTable)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("QueryMerchantRelationsInfo", "MerchantRelations", FormMethod.Post, new { criteriaInfo = Model }))
{
    if (Model.MerchantRelationComboList != null && Model.MerchantRelationComboList.Count() > 0)
    { 
        <div class="criteria-form criteria-form-three-col">
            <div class="clearfix">
                <div class="three-column-left">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MainStoreFlagDscr, Web.Constants.CompenentNameConstants.DisplayTemplates.DisplayTextForTable)
                </div>
                <div class="three-column-middle">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SelectedMerchantType, Web.Constants.CompenentNameConstants.DisplayTemplates.DisplayDropdown, new { SelectItems = Model.MerchantRelationComboList })
                </div>
                <div class="three-column-right">
                    <input type="submit" class="nar-btn nar-form-size75" value="Göster" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

And my controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult QueryMerchantRelations(MerchantRelationsViewModel merchantRelationsViewModel )
    {
        //Call First service and set into view model for second criteria search


        return View("Index", merchantRelationsViewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult QueryMerchantRelationsInfo(MerchantRelationsViewModel merchantRelationsViewModel)
    {
        //Call second service for retrieving second data

        return View("Index", merchantRelationsViewModel);
    }
```

When i call QueryMerchantRelationsInfo MerchantRelationsViewModel comes empty. I'm trying to give models in HTML.BeginForm parameter but nothing changes. Im tried to use hidden s and i cant give there entire model. Is there any way to do it without j query ajax call?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use PartialViews and Ajax. Make your controllers to return PartialView. And in the view render the partial views and use Ajax to post form.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what are you trying to accomplish but, update your view to

```
<div class="criteria-form criteria-form-three-col">
    <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="three-column-left">
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.MerchantNumber)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m=>Model.MerchantNumber)
        </div>
        <div class="three-column-middle">
            <input type="submit" class="nar-btn nar-form-size75" value="Bul" />
        </div>
        <div class="three-column-right">
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.SignName)
             @Html.HiddenFor(m=>Model.SignName)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
     @using (Html.BeginForm("QueryMerchantRelationsInfo", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { criteriaInfo = Model }))
 {
@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.MerchantNumber)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.SelectedMerchantType)
if (Model.MerchantRelationComboList != null && Model.MerchantRelationComboList.Count() > 0)
{ 
<div class="criteria-form criteria-form-three-col">
    <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="three-column-left">
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MainStoreFlagDscr)
        </div>
        <div class="three-column-middle">
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SelectedMerchantType, new { SelectItems =           Model.MerchantRelationComboList })
        </div>
        <div class="three-column-right">
            <input type="submit" class="nar-btn nar-form-size75" value="Göster" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    }
 }
```

Comment: We don't want to loose retrieved data from first service.